# Why is Bash mistaking the Git checkout parameter as a command in this script?

Tags: bash, git

I wrote this Bash script to install [Saleor](https://github.com/saleor/saleor).

When the script gets to line 605, it throws an error:

```
Deploy_Saleor/deploy.sh: line 605: [: missing `]'
Deploy_Saleor/deploy.sh: line 605: '2.11.1': command not found
```

Here's the Bash script from line 605:

```bash
if [ "vOPT" = "true" || $VERSION != "" ]; then
        # Checkout the specified version
        sudo -u $UN git checkout $VERSION
        wait
fi
```

The entire project is [located here](https://github.com/thewhiterabbit/Deploy_Saleor) if that helps.

I've tried this script with the single quotes, without them, and with backticks as the error hints, but the error will persist regardless of what surrounds the checkout `version`.

If `git checkout 2.11.1` is typed directly into the command line, the version checkout works as expected:

```
cd ~/saleor
git checkout 2.11.1
```

```
Note: switching to '2.11.1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 3848810d0 Bump to 2.11.1
```

So, what is causing Bash to think that `2.11.1` is a command and not a parameter?

Adding set -x at line 604 makes this appear...

```
+ '[' vOPT = true
Deploy_Saleor/deploy.sh: line 606: [: missing `]'
+ ''\''2.11.1'\''' '!=' '' ']'
Deploy_Saleor/deploy.sh: line 606: '2.11.1': command not found
```

Comment: If you `set -x` just before that section of code, what does the trace output look like?

Comment: `+ '[' vOPT = true`
Deploy_Saleor/deploy.sh: line 606: [: missing `]'
+ ''\''2.11.1'\''' '!=' '' ']'
`Deploy_Saleor/deploy.sh: line 606: '2.11.1': command not found`

What does that even mean? It looks like it's trying to

Comment: It would probably work better if you updated your answer to include that information, since comments don't allow for proper code formatting.

Comment: @larsks, done. I don't understand that output at all. It looks like regex to me.

Comment: Looks like there's much more in $VERSION than you might think. How do you populate VERSION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing the `||` operator. That's a special shell expression used to chain commands together (and execute the second if the first fails). It's not a boolean "or". You want either:

```
if [ "vOPT" = "true" -o "$VERSION" != "" ]; then
```

Or:

```
if [ "vOPT" = "true" ] || [ "$VERSION" != "" ]; then
```

In the first example, `-o` is a boolean "or". See `help test` for more information.

In the second example, we have `if <command 1> || <command 2>; then`. If the first command fails, the shell executes the second command, and the result of the pipeline is the exit code from that second command.

Note that I've quoted `$VERSION` here as `"$VERSION"`, which will prevent a different error if `$VERSION` is empty:

```
$ [ "vOPT" = "true" -o $VERSION != "" ]
-bash: [: too many arguments
$ [ "vOPT" = "true" ] || [ $VERSION != "" ]
-bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
```

Comment: Nope, same error. Although your observation helps with the comparison, it doesn't change the error state at all.

Comment: I suspect you forgot to quote `"$VERSION"` as I suggested here.

Comment: Note that in bash (but not all other shells), you can use `[[ ]]` ("conditional expressions") instead of `[ ]` (which is equivalent to the `test` command). The syntax is fairly similar, but in a `[[ ]]` expression, you *can* use `||` and `&&` as logical operators. See [BashFAQ #31: What is the difference between `test`, `[` and `[[` ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)